# Put data frame into array in r

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I Have two data frames :

The first one :

```
c1.df1 <- c(10, 55, 3)
c2.df1 <- c(-5, 18, 60)
df1 <- data.frame(c1.df1, c2.df1)
rownames(df1) <- c("row1", "row2", "row3")
colnames(df1) <- c("col1", "col2")
```

The result :

```
     col1 col2
row1   10   -5
row2   55   18
row3    3   60
```

The seconde one :

```
c1.df2 <- c(12, -99, 98)
c2.df2 <- c(-55, 8, 45)
df2 <- data.frame(c1.df2, c2.df2)
rownames(df2) <- c("row1", "row2", "row3")
colnames(df2) <- c("col1", "col2")
```

The result :

```
     col1 col2
row1   12  -55
row2  -99    8
row3   98   45
```

i want to put the two of them into an array, and get as result:

```
, , 1
     col1 col2
row1   10   -5
row2   55   18
row3    3   60

, , 2
    Col1 Col2
row1   12  -55
row2  -99    8
row3   98   45
```

I tried :

```
res <- array(c(df1, df2), c(3, 2, 2))
```

but i do not get what i want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to use `unlist`

```
array(c(unlist(df1), unlist(df2)), c(3, 2, 2), 
            dimnames=list(rownames(df1), colnames(df1)))
```

Comment: @Bilal If you need that, you can use the `dimnames` argument in `array`.  Please check the update.